# Place link on title in Markdown

Tags: markdown

I'm editing content in markdown, and I was wondering if theres any way to add a link on a title?

I've tried this:
[I'm an inline-style link](## title)

[]

"## Title"

(https://www.google.com)

But none of these seems to work.

Any ideas?

Comment: What do you mean by “add a link on a title”? Title as in h1, or what? Do you maybe mean the other way around - you have a link, and want to add a title attribute to it? (Nah, that can’t be it either, because the solution to that is found with 10 secs of googling.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you mean something like:

```
## [my title with link](/foobar)
```

which renders as:

### [my title with link](/foobar)